# C# return double value from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I want to return a `double` value from a stored procedure so I can call it from a form and multiplication its value in the value of the text box.

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Weight]
    @ID INT,
    @Weight FLOAT OUTPUT
AS
    SELECT @Weight = [Weight] 
    FROM [Item]
    WHERE ID_Item = @ID
```

This is my data access layer class:

```
class DataAccessLayer
{
    SqlConnection sqlconnection;

    public DataAccessLayer()
    {
        PL.FRM_LOGIN frm = new PL.FRM_LOGIN();
        sqlconnection = new SqlConnection("Server='"+System.Environment.MachineName+"';DataBase='"+frm.txtDataBase.Text+"';Integrated Security=true");          
    }

    // Method to open the connection
    public void Open()
    {
        if(sqlconnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            sqlconnection.Open();
        }
    }

    // Method to close the connection
    public void Close()
    {
        if(sqlconnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            sqlconnection.Close();
        }
    }

    // Method to read data from database
    public DataTable SelectData(string stored_procedure, SqlParameter[] param)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcmd.CommandText = stored_procedure;
        sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;

        if (param != null)
        {
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        }

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        return dt;
    }

    // Method to insert, update and delete data from database
    public void ExecuteCommand(string stored_procedure, SqlParameter[] param)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcmd.CommandText = stored_procedure;
        sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;

        if (param != null)
        {         
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);           
        }

        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I want to create a class in the business layer with a method that can return the value - for example

```
public void Get_Weight(int ID, double UWeight)
{
    DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
    DAL.Open();

    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];

    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
    param[0].Value = ID;

    param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Weight", SqlDbType.Float);
    param[1].Value = UWeight;
    param[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    DAL.ExecuteCommand("Get_Weight", param);
    DAL.Close();
}
```

And after that, I call that method from the form

```
void CalculateWeight()
{           
    if (txtLength.Text != string.Empty && cmbName.Text != null)
    {
        txtWeight.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtLength.Text) *(//the code)).ToString();
    }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: You need to use Explore something called ExecuteScalar method of SqlCommand.

Comment: OUTPUT parameters are not part of the result set. You must access the `Value` of the `SqlParameter` after executing the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were a code review I would have a number of issues with your approach to a Data Access Layer, but to solve your immediate problem I would suggest you change your `Get_Weight` method to return a double and not take a `UWeight` argument. Since your OUTPUT parameter is only set and not also used as input, you can give it a value of `DBNull.Value`. Lastly, it looks like you might have a typo in your procedure, is the column name really "Wight"?

```
public double Get_Weight(int ID)
{
    DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
    DAL.Open();
    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];

    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
    param[0].Value = ID;

    param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Weight", SqlDbType.Float);
    param[1].Value = DBNull.Value;
    param[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    DAL.ExcuteCommande("Get_Weight", param);
    DAL.Close();

    double weight = 0.0;
    if(double.TryParse(param[1]?.Value?.ToString(), out weight)
    {
       return weight;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("No Item found for given ID");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help ,yes my column name is "Wight" ,when i run the code i get this error :Error CS0161 'CLS_ItemQte.Get_Weight(int)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: Yeah, you need to fill in the "else" part or return a value however is appropriate for your system.

Comment: i want to return a vaule of "Wight" column so i can use it in my form,how i can do that ,sorry for the trouble

Comment: I can't know what business logic is appropriate for your system, but check my edit. The method will now return the weight or throw an exception if the ID didn't match any rows.

Answer (score -1):

Use ExecuteScalar to get a value from a stored procedure

```
public double ExcuteCommande(string stored_procedure,SqlParameter[] param)
{
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlcmd.CommandText = stored_procedure;
    sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;
    if (param!=null)
    {         
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);           
    }
    var back=sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar();
    double result;
    double.TryParse(back.ToString(), out result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: OP is using an `OUTPUT` parameter, `ExecuteScalar` will not work with that.

Comment: thanks for your help,can you help me to create class with  a method that can excute that commande